# How can I extract an .xz archive graphically on Mac OS X 10.4?

Tags: software-recommendation, macos, archive

Recent versions of StuffIt will extract [`.xz`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz) archives, but they will not run on Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger. And using something like [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/), it should be possible to install `xz-utils` on 10.4, so that `.xz` archives can be extracted from the Terminal.

But is there any graphical application that will run on Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger, and which will extract `.xz` files?

It's OK if this application supports extracting `.tar.xz` archives in a single step, but not necessary, because if it extracts the `.tar.xz` file to a `.tar` file, even an older version of StuffIt can extract that.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'd give [The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com/) a try. It's free, graphical, supports 10.4 and can extract `.xz` archives. There is also a [CLI version](https://theunarchiver.com/command-line).

Another option is [Keka](https://www.keka.io/) it's free (as in beer, newer releases are not open source) and [older versions](https://www.keka.io/#legacy) support older releases of macOS. For those that prefer that, it's also available in the [Mac App Store](https://mas.keka.io/).

Answer (score 86):

Not graphically, but this showed up in searches so for those of us who want to do it from the command line using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
$ brew install xz
$ xz -d to-extract.xz
```

Answer (score 55):

I've used the following native command on mac:

```
gunzip filename.xz
```

This won't work on OS X Tiger (which was first released in 2005), but it works fine on more recent versions of macOS.

Comment: `gzip -d filename.xz` also works for me.

Answer (score 7):

The `tar -xzf` command didn't work for me, but I installed XZ utils http://macpkg.sourceforge.net/ and then `unxz filename.tar.xz`.  Then you can just use the command `tar xf filename.tar` to open the tarball.  I have OSX Mountain Lion (version 10.8.5).

Comment: The reason is that the option `-z` specifies gzip compression/decompression. The right option for xz is `-J`. But in fact, modern `tar` implementations do not require you to specify the decompression algorithm. Just `tar -xf` is fine.

Answer (score 6):

On a mac, you can open up the terminal and use the command `tar -xzf filename.xz` if you're not looking to download a new App just for `.xz` archives

Answer (score 5):

MacOS 10.9 and later natively support **xz** (but the **Finder** works only on **tar.xz** files) according to a comment in reply to the similar excellent question at [Can MacOSX 10.7 open tar.lzma files](https://Apple.StackExchange.com/questions/212838/can-macosx-10-7-open-tar-lzma-files)

My tests show the MacOS 10.11 **Finder** fails to graphically decompress plain **xz** files unless they contain tar format.  MacOS 10.10 suffers the same bug according to the article at https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/archive-utility-xz

however the command line programs **gunzip**, **gzcat** and **zcat** automagically hack all **xz** files.

Comment: "XZ considered harmful" — every *xz* user should read _Xz format inadequate for long-term archiving_  https://www.nongnu.org/lzip/xz_inadequate.html