# How to unzip .xz

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, compression

How can I unzip a .xz file?
Archive utility failed.
Is there an app that I should get to do it?
(Mac Pro, OS X Yosemite 10.10.5)

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/233635/21339 says `gunzip` works on .xz files.  I've tested it on High Sierra 10.13.6.  Does it work on Yosemite?

Comment: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/archive-utility-xz.html suggests that Archive Uitlity can handle .tar.xz files in Yosemite, so maybe `gunzip` gained general xz support at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would give The Unarchiver a go. You can download it [directly](https://dl.devmate.com/com.macpaw.site.theunarchiver/TheUnarchiver.zip) or, if you prefer, via the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12).

**Note:** I am not affiliated with this product.

Answer (score 1):

In Mavericks (10.9.5), you can use `gunzip` in a terminal to extract `.xz` files - so it is sure to also work on Yosemite.

---

Note: The library `liblzma` is required to extract `.xz` files.

Prior to Mavericks, `.xz` can *not* be extracted by the native gunzip on OS X because this library is not present. For example, OS X Mountain Lion does not have `/usr/lib/liblzma.dylib`, nor `/usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib`, see [this post](https://github.com/shadowspawn/nvh/issues/8#issuecomment-531297393) and the table from [this post](https://github.com/shadowspawn/nvh/issues/8#issuecomment-529111011).

This [post](https://github.com/shadowspawn/nvh/issues/8#issuecomment-526798827) states:

> As [this StackOverflow answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271842/create-tar-archive-with-xz-compression/271853#271853) rightly points out, the xz/lzma feature of bsdtar is configurable at compile time. The feature is present back to macOS 10.7, but it is [configured](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libarchive/libarchive-23/config.h.auto.html) *[off](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libarchive/libarchive-25.1/config.h.auto.html)* until [macOS 10.9](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libarchive/libarchive-29/config.h.auto.html).

Also of interest, from this [post](https://github.com/shadowspawn/nvh/issues/8#issuecomment-526329235):

> Found some info about OS X and libarchive versions. According to this: https://opensource.apple.com/
>
> OS X 10.6.x shipped with libarchive 2.6.2. And OS X 10.7.x shipped with libarchive 2.8.3.
>
> (2.8.3 is still used in Mojave, albeit with various, minor-looking, darwin-specific patches accumulated over the years if I understand correctly. For example, see [libarchive.plist](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libarchive/libarchive-54.250.1/libarchive.plist.auto.html) from macOS Mojave 10.14.5 for details.)

For more information, read this thread:
[XZ compression support #8](https://github.com/shadowspawn/nvh/issues/8)